# python & scrapy bashfile sequential conflict

Tags: python, bash, scrapy, conflict

**Set-up**

I've got a Scrapy spider named `rooms`, a Python script named `liverpool_rooms.py` and an existing spider output file from a previous 'run' named `liverpool_rooms.csv` .

---

**Problem**

I want to sequentially activate the spider and the script from a bash file named `start_liverpool.txt`.

Since Scrapy cannot overwrite but only append output to existing files, prior to this sequential activation I want to remove `liverpool_rooms.csv` in order for Scrapy to create a new `liverpool_rooms.csv`.

The bashfile follows,

1. Remove existing file `liverpool_rooms.csv`
2. Run spider `rooms`
3. Run script `liverpool_rooms.py`

Important: `liverpool_rooms.py` imports spider export `liverpool_rooms.csv`.

---

**Bashfile**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Users/.../spiders
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
rm liverpool_rooms.csv &&
scrapy crawl rooms -o liverpool_rooms.csv &&
python liverpool_rooms.py
```

---

**Conflict**

I receive an error for `liverpool_rooms.py` when running the bashfile stating `liverpool_rooms.csv` cannot be found. This is because `rm liverpool_rooms.csv` removes the .csv file, and apparently `python liverpool_rooms.py` is checked on errors before running the spider.

How can I prevent this checking of `liverpool_rooms.py` on errors prior to running the spider?

Comment: Was your intention to run the `Run spider rooms` as a background process ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Ultimately, I want to run the bash file once a week by means of a cron job. I want it to follow the steps 1. 2. and 3. sequentially.

Comment: Since you have the statements separated by `&&` the 2nd and 3rd statements won't be executed if 1st fails (when the csv file is not found, `rm` will fail).

Comment: Is it your intention to delete the file only if it exists and proceed with 2) and 3) if it does not exist?

Comment: Ah, I understand. I've also tried `rm liverpool_rooms.csv; scrapy crawl rooms -o liverpool_rooms.csv; python liverpool_rooms.py`, but it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

On the first run of this script there won't be a csv file to remove and so the script fails.

**Solution:**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Users/.../spiders
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH
rm liverpool_rooms.csv ; true
scrapy crawl rooms -o liverpool_rooms.csv
python liverpool_rooms.py
```

**Explanation:**

- the `; true` makes the script ignore any errors when doing the remove
- I removed the `&&` as it is not necessary inside a script